# jQuery autocomplete - data.split is not a function

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am using jQuery plugin autocomplete in web application and i pass simple json data to the autocomplete.
When i pass data this way, by the variable words. Autocomlete works fine.

```
var words = ["benzina","best","benátská noc","bez realitky","beroun","bershka","bernard","beskydy","belgie","berlin"];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#suggest").autocomplete(words, {
    formatItem: function(data, i, n) {
      return data[0];
    },  
      width: 342
  });
});
```

But when I download it from server I get this error message "data.split is not a function". 
I also set header Content-type: application/json in my server side script. I also try set option in autocommplete dataType: 'json', but still the same problem. 
When i parse data in autocomplete option parse: function(data) { .. } it looks, that data are OK, but i cannot read it in formatItem. Do you have got any idea?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#suggest").autocomplete("ajax.php?gsug="+whisp_id, {
    formatItem: function(data, i, n) {
      return data[0];
    },  
      width: 342
  });
});
```

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: which jQuery autocomplete are you using?  There is more than one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421966/is-there-more-than-one-jquery-autocomplete-widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you use this autocomplete: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions

This autocomplete expects for remote data not an array, it expects a string, each entry in a separate line.

So what you can do: 
Return the expected response or build your own parse-function for the request(can be setup as an option).
This function has to return an array with objects, where the objects have the members data,value,result (take a look at the original parse-method in autocomplete.js to see what is what)

Furthermore: Be sure that ajax.php output's a valid json-string(use php's json_encode if you don't do yet). And set the dataType to 'json', like you already tried before.

Comment: I wrote an article a while ago about creating a JSON `parse` method for that version of AutoComplete - http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2008/10/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-with-json-data/. FYI, Jörn’s plugin has been deprecated in favour of the jQuery UI version which accepts JSON data natively - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 1):

because that url is just string not a json data, first you need to get the data.

try this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php?gsug="+whisp_id,
      cache: false,
      success: function(jsondata){
          $("#suggest").autocomplete(jsondata, {
            formatItem: function(data, i, n) {
              return data[0];
            },  
              width: 342
          });
      }
    });
});
```